# Beamer theme Amsterdam

Tags: beamer, themes, mini-frames

I would like to modify beamer theme Amsterdam (downloaded from the side http://latex.simon04.net the first topic) in this way:

In headlines I would like to get rid of the circles under the name of sections.

Comment: Could you edit your question and make it a little bit more specific on what exactly does not work as you expected it, please?

Comment: Your question is not very clear...what did you expect? Can you give an minimum working example ...

Comment: OK, good for you! I count the number of question marks and get zero, so I assume this was just for our information. If you'd like us to help you, it would make it a lot easier for us if you try making the changes you want, and then tell us what, if anything, went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the following modified code of `beamerthemeAmsterdam.sty` and save as `beamerthemeAmsterdamTeXsx.sty`. It uses `\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal` instead of `\insertnavigation` in order to suppress the small circles representing the individual frames.

```
\DeclareOptionBeamer{compress}{\beamer@compresstrue}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\mode<presentation>

\useoutertheme[footline=authortitle]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\usecolortheme{orchid}

\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{rgb}{0.137,0.466,0.741}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=beamer@blendedblue}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=black}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\mode
<all>
```

You can then use it via `\usetheme{AmsterdamTeXsx}` in your preamble.

[image: TOC of modified theme]